# Tweak make package failed: libfakeroot.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, mach-o, fakeroot

I was trying to make my first tweak for ios using [Theos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Definitions).
And I just used a default tweak template(`nic.pl`), didnt change anything, I got this error when I tried to run `make package`:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library '/usr/local/Cellar/fakeroot/1.22/lib/libfakeroot.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/Cellar/fakeroot/1.22/lib/libfakeroot.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/Cellar/fakeroot/1.22/lib/libfakeroot-0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

/usr/local/bin/fakeroot: line 181:  3701 Abort trap: 6           FAKEROOTKEY=$FAKEROOTKEY DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="$LIB" "$@"
make: *** [internal-package] Error 134
```

More Information:

Env: Darwin MacBook pro 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0

IOS sdk: I am using the newest version of SDK(iosdk11) & Xcode(9.0), I also tried different SDK, but no luck, I assume the problem here is fake root did not generate compatible binary.

Fakeroot: I just did `brew install fakeroot` to install.

libfakeroot info: `/usr/local/Cellar/fakeroot/1.22/lib/libfakeroot.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`.

Comment: You're trying to link your iOS binary against a macOS shared library. That cannot possibly work, you need to get hold of a libfakeroot compiled for iOS, or compile it yourself (if there's something where you can specify C compiler, using `xcrun -sdk iphoneos gcc` might just be enough to get you an iOS binary). Moreover, if you intend to publish this tweak, you either need to create a separate package for libfakeroot and add that as a dependency, or link your tweak statically against it. If you do not do that, then your tweak will not be able to find libfakeroot on the target system.

Comment: @Siguza Thx for your answer, I am not familiar with how theos work tbh, is there anyway I can do to change xcrun default sdk to be iphoneos sdk, and default compiler to be iphone:clang? I tried adding `TARGET = iphone:clang` in Makefile under my tweak dir but didn't work.

Comment: Also can you tell me how to compile libfakeroot.dylib myself? THx!